# Tomcat 8.5 - Is Certificate/SSL required for HTTP2

Tags: tomcat, http2, tomcat8.5

I found  [Http2Protocol](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/coyote/http2/Http2Protocol.html) doc, that it doesn't supports HTTPS?

> Some protocols (e.g. HTTP/2) only support HTTP upgrade over non-secure connections.

Is it a typo, or I **must** use HTTP and not HTTPS when using Tomcat HTTP2 or am I missing something?

Because I added [UpgradeProtocol](https://geekflare.com/tomcat-http2/) to

> ```
> <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
> ```

For HTTP connector:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"/>
```

And added relevant alpn jar to JAVA_OPT using `-Xbootclasspath/p:/path/to/alpn-boot.jar`

But it doesn't find matching rule:

> ```
> org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement   No rules found matching 'Server/Service/UpgradeProtocol'.
> ```

I also tried to add to connector [openssl implementation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html) but same results

```
sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLImplementation"
```

> Because Java 8's TLS implementation does not support ALPN (which is required for HTTP/2 over TLS), you must be using an OpenSSL based TLS implementation to enable HTTP/2 support. See the sslImplementationName attribute of the Connector

Must I use Certificate/SSL for HTTP2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encryption is [de facto mandatory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http/2#Encryption) to use http/2:

> Although the standard itself does not require usage of encryption, all
>   major client implementations (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, IE,
>   Edge) have stated that they will only support HTTP/2 over TLS ...

So you'll need a fully configured `SSLHostConfig` with `Certificate` in order to run HTTP/2 over TLS.

A connector like this may work for you:

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" port="8443"
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https"
    secure="true"
    sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLImplementation">
    <SSLHostConfig certificateVerification="none"
        sslProtocol="TLS">
        <Certificate certificateKeyAlias="myKeyAlias"
            certificateKeystoreFile="/path/to/my/keystore.jks"
            certificateKeystorePassword="myPassword"
            certificateKeystoreType="JKS">
        </Certificate>
    </SSLHostConfig>
    <UpgradeProtocol
        className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
</Connector>
```

If you want to use NIO2, change `protocol` to `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol`.

If you want to use SSL without OpenSSL but use the java implementation JSSE instead, change `sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation"` (if provided by your JRE).

---

Despite the fact that browsers won't upgrade to http/2 on unencrypted connections, it's technically possible to configure a http/2 connector on Apache Tomcat without SSL and use it e.g. with CURL - manually enforcing the http/2 upgrade:

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="false" maxThreads="150" port="8444" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" secure="false">
    <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol"/>
</Connector>
```

CURL debug output:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8444 -v --http2
...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8444 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8444
> User-Agent: curl/7.60.0
> Accept: */*
> Connection: Upgrade, HTTP2-Settings
> Upgrade: h2c
> HTTP2-Settings: AAMAAABkAARAAAAAAAIAAAAA
>
< HTTP/1.1 101
< Connection: Upgrade
< Upgrade: h2c
< Date: Mon, 28 Oct 2019 12:06:18 GMT
* Received 101
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 200)!
< HTTP/2 200
< content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
< date: Mon, 28 Oct 2019 12:06:18 GMT
<
```

Comment: But my question is about using HTTP2  **without SSL**

Comment: Your question so far reads like you try to enable http2 upgrade and SSL for your http-connector: "I found Http2Protocol doc, that it doesn't supports HTTPS?" - "Is it a typo, or I must use HTTP and not HTTPS" - "`<Connector ... secure="true"/>`". I don't see an indication that you want to use http2 without SSL/TLS. I updated my answer @user7294900

Comment: So the quote *Some protocols (e.g. HTTP/2) only support HTTP upgrade over non-secure connections* should be without `non-`?

Comment: @user7294900 I updated my answer again. I'd aggree removing the 'non' would read more correct and help users getting to a http/2 connector working with their browser more quickly. Technically the entire quote does not seem to make sense as http/2 is also possible without encryption.

Comment: Thank you, you define as `secure="false"`, but with `scheme="https"`, is HTTPS a must?

Comment: @user7294900 no, this can be removed either.